# Scala and JPA Results Lists

Tags: list, scala, jpa

Scala noob i'm afraid:

I have the following declared class variable which will the objects I read from the database:

```
val options = mutable.LinkedList[DivisionSelectOption]()
```

I then use JPA to get a List of all rows from a table:

```
val divisionOptions = em.createNamedQuery("SelectOption.all", classOf[SelectOption]) getResultList
/* Wrap java List in Scala List */
val wrappedOptions = JListWrapper.apply(divisionOptions)
/* Store the wrappedOptions in the class variable */
options += wrappedOptions
```

However, the last line has an error:

```
Type Expected: String, actual JListWrapper[SelectOption]
```

Can anyone help with what I am doing wrong? I'm just trying to populate the `options` object with the result of the DB call.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What (probably) is happening is that a `JlistWrapper[SelectOption]` isn't a `DivisionSelectOption`, so the method `+=` isn't applicable to it. That being the case, it is trying other stuff, and giving a final error on this:

```
options = options + wrappedOptions
```

That is a rewriting Scala can do to make things like `x += 1` work for `var x`. The `+` method is present on all objects, but it takes a `String` as parameter -- that's so one can write stuff like `options + ":"` and have that work as in Java. But since `wrappedOptions` isn't a `String`, it complains.

Roundabout and confusing, I know, and even Odersky regrets his decision with regards to `+`. Let that be a lesson: if you thing of adding a method to `Any`, think *really* hard before doing it.